# redis.exceptions.ResponseError: MOVED error in redis set operation

Tags: javascript, python, redis

I have created a Redis cluster with 30 instances (15 masters/ 15 nodes). With python code i connected to these instances, i found the masters and then i wanted to add some keys to them.

```
def settomasters(port, host):
    r = redis.Redis( host=host, port=port )
    r.set("key"+port,"value")
```

Error:

> redis.exceptions.ResponseError: MOVED 12539 127.0.0.1:30012

If i try to set key from `redis-cli -c -p portofmyinstance` sometimes i get a redirection message that tells where the keys stored.

I know that in case of get requests for example, a smart client is needed in order to redirect the requests to the correct node (the node that holds the key) otherwise a moved error occurs. Is it the same situation? I need to catch the redis.exceptions.ResponseError and try to set again?

```
while True:
    try:
        r.set("key","value")
        break
    except:
        print "error"
        pass
```

My first try was above code but without solution. The set operation never succeeds.

On the other hand below code in javascript does not throw an error and i cannot figure the reason:

```
var redis = require('redis-stream'),
client = new redis(30001, '127.0.0.1');

// Open stream
var stream = client.stream();

// Example of setting 200 records
for(var record = 0; record <200; record++) {
    var command = ['set', 'qwerty' + record, 'QWERTYUIOP'];  
    stream.redis.write( redis.parse(command) );
}

stream.on('close', function () {
console.log('Completed!');
});

// Close the stream after batch insert
stream.end();
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

with a redis cluster you can use the normal redis client only if you "find for the certain key the slot that belongs and then the slots that each master serves. With this information i can set keys to the correct node without moved redirection errors." as @Antonis said. Otherwise you need http://redis-py-cluster.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: Half-true. Certainly this is the correct way but not the absolute. I manage to solve my problem by find for the certain key the slot that belongs and then the slots that each master serves. With this information i can set keys to the correct node without moved redirection errors